# file:// links in XUL browser

Tags: firefox, xul

I'm trying to get the XUL browser in a Firefox app to display images from "file://" locations, from a page at `http://localhost`.

I'm running the app with Firefox 30.

I've tried this, but to no avail :

```
var branch = browser.preferences.getBranch("capability.policy");
branch.setCharPref("policynames", "localfilelinks");
branch.setCharPref("localfilelinks.sites", "http://localhost");
branch.setCharPref("localfilelinks.checkloaduri.enabled", "allAccess");
```

What's the correct way of allowing file links ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea run `file://` content inside `http://`. Why can't you use `chrome://` or `http://` for the images. `chrome://` URLs are easy to locate and they come always with your app.

Comment: If it's restricted to localhost, I'm not sure what the security implication would be.

I can't do it with chrome, my app needs full filesystem access from the browser.

Comment: What's the pourpose of the application? Why you can't use one single protocol?